# I have created a HTML form but don't know what to put in the aspx.cs

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have created a HTML form but don't know what to put in the `aspx.cs`.
I have written this in the `Page_load` part but not sure of the submit and the `name` and `address` part.

html

```
    <asp:Label ID="Name" runat="server" Text="Name" Width="150px"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" OnTextChanged="TextBox1_TextChanged" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="Address" runat="server" Height="50px" Text="Address" Width="150px"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Height="50px" OnTextChanged="TextBox2_TextChanged" Width="400px"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <br />
 &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Save" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Response.Write(Request.Form.Get("text"));
}

protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       ??name
}

protected void TextBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       ??Address
}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       ??Submit
}

public partial class bookings : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write(Request.Form.Get("text"));
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve from this screen/form??

Comment: It depends on what you would like to achive, doubt you will be using the TextChanged events though. Most likely you will only be using the OnClick event to process the data

Comment: @TejuMB Its a form and I want it to post to the server

Comment: @Dave 
I have the form and the ASPX page I need to know the coding for the aspx.cs page

Comment: If you wanto tovalidate it or save it to the database , you have to learn ADO.NET to perform such operation.

Comment: @TejuMB I just need to enter the name and address on the form then submit it to the aspx  page

Comment: Have a look at some of these examples, we cant really help you without knowing a lot of other information like how you wish to connect to the DB, what DB you are using and if you would like to validate data etc. http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/webpages_examples.asp

Comment: @Dave I just need to enter the name and address on the form then submit it to the aspx page

Comment: What database engine will you be using?

Comment: @Dave  why dont you understand?? I am not using any db here

Comment: I cant understand what you are trying to do, do you want to just display the data on a different page?

Answer (score 0):

This is very basic question, and you can find it to do in lot of ways while googling.

Anyhow, You can write this button event to save the data ,provided your server ,database and login credentials .

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
           string connectionString = "Persist Security Info=False;User ID=sa;Password=123;Initial Catalog=AddressBook;Server=abc-PC";    
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tblName ([Name], Address) VALUES (@Name, @Address)");
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = connection;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", txtAddress.Text);
            connection.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }     
    }
```

[Complete video is here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sSBx9_eddmo)

Answer (score 0):

In your button click handler, you can inspect the values of the textboxes on the page. You will not need the TextBox_TextChanged handlers for this. Here is your Button_Click handler:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string name = TextBox1.Text;
   string address = TextBox2.Text;

   // Do something with your strings...
   Response.Write("Your name is : " + name + "<br />");
   Response.Write("Your address : " + address);
}
```

Comment: protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                 Response.Write("name")
        }




        protected void TextBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                Response.Write("address")
        }


protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string name = TextBox1.Text;
   string address = TextBox2.Text;




   // Do something with your strings...
}

Comment: I've edited my answer to demonstrate a simple way to parrot back the visitor's responses. A slightly more elegant solution might be to add a label to the page and use that to contain your response.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the POST method, you send the values for the HTML controls in a form to the page that is specified in the action attribute. To do this, follow these steps:

1. Create a new .htm page and name it Gatherdata_post.htm. To do this in Visual InterDev version 6.0, right-click the project node in the Project Explorer, click Add, click HTML Page, type Gatherdata_post.htm as the name of the page, and then click Open.
2. Paste the following code in the new page:NOTE: You should clear out the default code that InterDev adds when you initially create the page before you paste this code in the page. Otherwise, you will have redundant tags.

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<FORM action="RetrieveData_Post.asp" id=form1 method=post name=form1>
 First Name:
 <br>
 <INPUT id="txtFirstName" name="txtFirstName" >
 <br>
 Last Name:
 <br>
 <INPUT id="txtLastName" name="txtLastName" >
 <br>
 <INPUT type="submit" value="Submit"> 
</FORM>
</body>
</html>
```

3. Save the page. To do this, click Save Gatherdata_post.htm on the File menu in the Visual InterDev IDE.
4. Create another page named Retrievedata_post.asp. Paste the following code in the page, and save the page:

```html
<%@ Language=VBScript %>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<%
Response.Write("First Name: " & Request.Form("txtFirstName") & "<br>")
Response.Write("Last Name: " & Request.Form("txtLastName") & "<br>")
%>
</body>
</html>
```

5. Run Gatherdata_post.htm by right-clicking the page and selecting View in browser. Enter some values for the first and last names, and then click Submit. Note that the data that you entered in Getdata_post.htm has been sent through HTTP POST to the Retrievedata_post.asp page for retrieval using the Request.Form collection.

When you use the GET method, you send the values for the HTML controls in a form to the page that is specified in the action attribute in a manner that is similar to the POST approach that was described previously. However, you will notice that the values are sent in the QueryString. One main issue to consider when you use GET instead of POST is that the values are visible in the URL.

To use the GET method, follow these steps:

1. Create a new .htm page and name it Gatherdata_get.htm. To do this in Visual InterDev version 6.0, right-click the project node in the Project Explorer, click Add, click HTML Page, type Gatherdata_get.htm as the name of the page, and then click Open.
2. Paste the following code in the new page:NOTE: You should clear out the default code that InterDev adds when you initially create the page before you paste this code in the page. Otherwise, you will have redundant tags.

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<FORM action="RetrieveData_Get.asp" id=form1 method=GET name=form1>
 First Name:
 <br>
 <INPUT id="txtFirstName" name="txtFirstName" >
 <br>
 Last Name:
 <br>
 <INPUT id="txtLastName" name="txtLastName" >
 <br>
 <INPUT type="submit" value="Submit" id=submit1 name=submit1> 
</FORM>
</body>
</html>
```

3. Save the page. To do this, click Save Gatherdata_get.htm on the File menu in the Visual InterDev IDE.
4. Create another page named Retrievedata_get.asp. Paste the following code in the page, and save the page:

```html
<%@ Language=VBScript %>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<%
Response.Write("First Name: " & Request.QueryString("txtFirstName") & "<br>")
Response.Write("Last Name: " & Request.QueryString("txtLastName") & "<br>")
%>
</body>
</html>
```

5.Run Gatherdata_get.htm by right-clicking the page and selecting View in browser. Enter some values for the first and last names, and then click Submit. Note that the data that is entered in Getdata_get.htm is sent through GET to the Retrievedata_get.asp page for retrieval using the Request.QueryString collection. As you have seen, the QueryString collection is where your data is made available to the retrieving ASP page when you use GET as the action for the sending page, and the Form collection is used to retrieve the data when you implement POST.